# Swift 3 custom parameter types

Tags: function, swift3, parameters, enums, typedef

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, I can't find an answer. I would like to create custom parameter types for a function.

Typedef?/Define type

```
direction
{
    LeftToRight,
    RightToLeft
};
```

Function:

```
class func animateIn (dir:direction)
{
    if dir = LeftToRight
    {
        // animate left to right
    }
    else
    {
        // animate right to left
    }
}
```

Call:

```
animateIn (dir:LeftToRight)
```

Comment: You can use enum.
 `enum Direction {
            case leftToRight, rightToLeft
        }
        let direction: Direction = .rightToLeft`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum` seems the perfect candidate for this use. If you plan to have more cases in the `enum`, a switch statement also seems to be more feasible inside the function.

```
enum Direction {
    case leftToRight, rightToLeft
}

class func animateIn(dir: Direction){
    switch dir{
    case .leftToRight:
        //do something
    case .rightToLeft:
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm  Thank you sir! 

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Direction
{
    case leftToRight, rightToLeft
}
```

Function:

```
class func animateIn(dir:Direction)
{
    switch dir {
    case .leftToRight:
        // animate left to right
    default:
        // animate right to left    
    }
}
```

Call:

```
animateIn(dir:.leftToRight)
```

Comment: It's better to explicitly name the case `.rightToLeft` rather than making it inferred from `default`. It's clearer that way.